# ERROR: href Attribute is not working in HTML <A> TAG

Tags: url, href, html

href attribute is not working in the code mentioned below:

```
<section class="loginform" style="min-width: 600px; width: 70%; margin: 40px auto;">
<fieldset style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px;">
<legend>AA</legend> 
<label> <br> </label>
<style>
.ball {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 120%, 0, 50% 120%, 100, color-stop(0%, #81e8f6), color-stop(10%, #76deef), color-stop(80%, #055194), color-stop(100%, #37526a));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 120%, circle cover, #81e8f6, #76deef 10%, #055194 80%, #37526a 100%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 120%, circle cover, #81e8f6, #76deef 10%, #055194 80%, #37526a 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(50% 120%, circle cover, #81e8f6, #76deef 10%, #055194 80%, #37526a 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(50% 120%, circle cover, #81e8f6, #76deef 10%, #055194 80%, #37526a 100%);
  cursor:pointer;
}
.ball:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 0px, 0, 50% 0px, 58, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(58%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 0px, circle cover, #ffffff, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 58%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 0px, circle cover, #ffffff, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 58%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(50% 0px, circle cover, #ffffff, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 58%);
  background: radial-gradient(50% 0px, circle cover, #ffffff, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 58%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: 2;
}

.ball .shadow {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 50, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), color-stop(40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
background: radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-26px);
-moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-26px);
-ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-26px);
-o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-26px);
transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-26px);
z-index: -1;
}
.stage {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-perspective: 200px;
  -moz-perspective: 200px;
  -ms-perspective: 200px;
  -o-perspective: 200px;
  perspective: 200px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
</style>

<ul> 
<li>
<section class="stage">
  <figure class="ball"><span class="shadow"></span><div style="line-height:45px; color:#00FFFF; text-align:center; font-size:16px;">
    1</div></figure>
</section> </li>

<li>
<section class="stage">
  <figure class="ball"><span class="shadow"></span><div style="line-height:45px; color:#FFFF00; text-align:center; font-size:16px;">
   <a href="http://www.test.com/aaa.php"> Test</a>
</div></figure>
</section> </li>
</ul>
    </fieldset> </section>
</section>
```

Can you please help me to resolve this error? 
Please note: Here , if I click on Test ; web page is not navigating click event to desired destination.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Spfg9/ works for me

Comment: What do you mean the attribute is not working? Are you unable to retrieve the value of the attribute, the link is not pointing to the right URL, the link fails to fire when clicked on...?

Comment: You sould provide more details about the context where you use this block of html.

Comment: @Terry ; I'm not able to navigate to respective URL on click on the link.

Comment: What do you mean "you can not"?

Comment: And why is there `li` tag alone? Is it so in your final code or that's just a piece?

Comment: @Agat I've added complete code to reproduce error.

Comment: @Danko I've added code to re-produce required error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because of your `:before` block:

```
.ball:before {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Being positioned as `absolute` its position becomes over the link and then obviously the link does not work.

To prevent that you can also make your `div` with the link positioned as absolute (you should also 'play' with z-index to make all that work (or just to ommit the one for ':before' element at all).

```
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:3;line-height:45px; color:#FFFF00; text-align:center; font-size:16px;">
   <a href="http://www.test.com/aaa.php"> Test</a>
</div>
```